# Does processElement() block broadcastProcessElement()?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I know that when broadcastProcessElement() is executing, processElement will not be executed, but is the vice versa also true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There’s a single thread for executing all of the user-implemented methods in the same task.